# Sorting an array of objects by length of one object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. And in each cards object has a property names **votedBy**, which stores userId of people giving the vote. I want to sort the array by the length of property votedBy. Note: Some object don't have votedBy property.

```
[{
  id: 'card1',
  text: "Item1",
  votedBy: {
             userId1: true,
             userId2: true
           }
 }, 
 {
  id: 'card2',
  text: 'Item 1',
  votedBy: {
             userId3: true
           }
 }, 
 {
  id: 'card3',
  text: 'Item 3'
 }, 
{
  id: 'card4',
  text: "Item4",
  votedBy: {
             userId5: true,
             userId6: true,
             userId7: true
           }
 }]
```

I try to use Array.sort like this

```
array.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(b.votedBy).length - Object.keys(a.votedBy).length )
```

And it works only if each object has to have a votedBy property. But some of my objects doens't have that property.

The outcome should look like this

```
[{
     {
      id: 'card4',
      text: "Item4",
      votedBy: {
                 userId5: true,
                 userId6: true,
                 userId7: true
               }
     },
    {
      id: 'card1',
      text: "Item1",
      votedBy: {
                 userId1: true,
                 userId2: true
               }
     }, 
     {
      id: 'card2',
      text: 'Item 1',
      votedBy: {
                 userId3: true
               }
     }, 
     {
      id: 'card3',
      text: 'Item 3'
     }, 
]
```

**Update**

```
array.sort((a, b) => (
  Boolean(b.votedBy) - Boolean(a.votedBy)
  || Object.keys(b.votedBy).length - Object.keys(a.votedBy).length
));
```

It works only if I have 1 object without sortedBy. If I have more than 1 object without sortedBy, there's an error

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object*

new test array should look like that

```
[{
  id: 'card1',
  text: "Item1",
  votedBy: {
             userId1: true,
             userId2: true
           }
 }, 
 {
  id: 'card2',
  text: 'Item 1',
  votedBy: {
             userId3: true
           }
 }, 
 {
  id: 'card3',
  text: 'Item 3'
 }, 
{
  id: 'card4',
  text: "Item4",
  votedBy: {
             userId5: true,
             userId6: true,
             userId7: true
           }
 },
 {
  id: 'card5',
  text: 'Item 5'
 } ]
```

**Update 2**

I manage to make it working by long and ugly code. Does anyone have nicer and shorter code ?

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.votedBy === undefined && b.votedBy === undefined)
  return Boolean(b.votedBy) - Boolean(a.votedBy)
  else if (a.votedBy === undefined) 
  return Object.keys(b.votedBy).length - Boolean(a.votedBy)
  else if (b.votedBy === undefined) 
  return Boolean(b.votedBy) - Object.keys(a.votedBy).length
  else return Object.keys(b.votedBy).length - Object.keys(a.votedBy).length
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort by whether the difference between the existence of `b.votedBy` and `a.votedBy`:

```
array.sort((a, b) => (
  Boolean(b.votedBy) - Boolean(a.votedBy)
  || (
    a.votedBy &&
    Object.keys(b.votedBy).length - Object.keys(a.votedBy).length
  )
));
```

```js
const array = [{
    id: 'card1',
    text: "Item1",
    votedBy: {
      userId1: true,
      userId2: true
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'card2',
    text: 'Item 1',
    votedBy: {
      userId3: true
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'card3',
    text: 'Item 3'
  },
  {
    id: 'card4',
    text: "Item4",
    votedBy: {
      userId5: true,
      userId6: true,
      userId7: true
    }
  },
  { id: 'card5', text: 'Item 5' } 
];

array.sort((a, b) => (
  Boolean(b.votedBy) - Boolean(a.votedBy)
  || (
    a.votedBy &&
    Object.keys(b.votedBy).length - Object.keys(a.votedBy).length
  )
));
console.log(array);
```

A shorter but more inelegant code that creates an unnecessary object would be:

```
array.sort((a, b) => (
  Object.keys(b.votedBy || {}).length - Object.keys(a.votedBy || {}).length
));
```

Note that if it's possible for `votedBy` to have a truthy non-object value, you'll have to be a bit more verbose:

```
(typeof b.votedBy === 'object') - (typeof a.votedBy === 'object')
```

Comment: small question, if I add a new object {     id: 'card5',
    text: 'Item 5' } to array. It shows error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. So your solution works only if the array has only 1 Object without votedBy ?

Comment: the error is caused because your added object doesn't have `votedBy` property - how should the algorithm behave if such an object is added?

Comment: the object without sortedBy should be at the bottom of the result

Comment: @tomen Oops, that's right, if there is more than one object without a `votedBy` property, they'll be sorted against each other, so the Boolean subtraction will evaluate to 0. If you don't care about how the objects without `votedBy` are sorted *with respect to each other*, you can just add another check that `a.votedBy` is truthy before comparing the length of the keys, see edit

Comment: Truthly impressive, I've tried hours for a short and clean code like this but still didn't figure it out. Many thanks